# Custom 404 Page Redirecting, but not showing the Custom Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, http-status-code-404, iis-6

I have tried to set up a Custom 404 page, and it is redirecting to that URL.  However, it's not showing the page it should be.  **IIS 6**

**So, I have the web.config setting AND I'm returning a 404 code on the NotFound.aspx page.**

**Web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/error/Default.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/NotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

**NotFound.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class error_NotFound : Custom.PageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404; 
    }    
}
```

You can see here that this:

https://www.mshsaa.org/notapage.aspx

...redirects to this:

https://www.mshsaa.org/error/NotFound.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/notapage.aspx

**NOTE** This does appear to work correctly on my local machine, but not on live.

**NOTE2** I see that there is also an IIS setting for a 404 Error that redirects.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the NotFound.aspx is both deployed and in the correct folder?

Comment: @JonathonChase It certainly appears to be there and in the correct folder.

Comment: Add `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` to `customErrors`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev That gives me a Runtime Error.  And it doesn't even seem to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code from my production server.

**web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/404.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/500.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

**404.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class error_NotFound : Custom.PageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        //do something with the exception
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.StatusCode = 404; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I get a runtime error and the page does not redirect when I use the ResponseRewrite option.